# What is the meaning of dimensions/units in mathematical equations?

Tags: applications, dimensional-analysis

In highschool I've always been taught the dimensions on the left hand side of the equation should always be equal to the dimensions of the right hand side, because we can't compare apples and oranges so to speak.

Eg: $5 g = 5 g$ is valid but $5 m = 5 g$ is not.

I haven't given this much thought, until recently a friend of mine came up with this question: "Since $e = mc^2$, and since $c$ is just a constant: doesn't that mean that energy is just mass with another unit?"

Is this wrong usage of dimensions in equations? If not then what is the real meaning of dimensions and units within equations?

Comment: "*constant*" is not the same thing as "*unitless*" / "*dimensionless*"; [$c$ is the speed of light in a vacuum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light), and therefore has whatever units of speed you prefer (e.g., meters/second).

Comment: Your friend is right about the relationship between energy and mass, although we usually say that matter is just another form in which energy manifests itself.

Comment: @ZevChonoles So the units always have to be consistent?
Let's say a person is connected to some kind of device. The device detects how many meters that person has ran, and for each meter the person has ran the device adds 1 gram of some material to a box.
Can we not represent this relation by Mass of box in grams = Distance the person ran in meters?

Comment: @xcrypt: Yes, the units should always be consistent, so no, you should not represent it that way. A correct statement would be
$$\frac{\text{mass of box in grams}}{\text{grams}}=\frac{\text{distance run in meters}}{\text{meters}}$$
Each side of this equation is a dimensionless number, whereas
$$\text{mass of box in grams}$$
is still a mass, and
$$\text{distance run in meters}$$
is still a distance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to leave a comment but I think this is an important point regarding your question: Particle physicists actually use the [electronvolt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron-volt) ($eV$), which is a unit of energy, as a unit of mass, because [mass and energy are equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence). They are using a [natural unit system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) where they define $c=1$. It should be noted, however, that one may not just choose arbitrary constants and declare that they are equal to one, because that might result in contradictory definitions, see e.g. the [fine-structure constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant). In fact, natural unit systems are much like what you do whenever you run a physics simulation on a computer: you must store the values of the physical quantities as dimensionless values in the computer memory and keep track of the dimensions in another way.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [Buckingham Pi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem), which formalizes some of the reasoning around dimensional analysis.  In short, one can indeed think of the different basic dimensions / units as different dimensions in a vector space.

See also [this mathoverflow page](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63749/dimensional-analysis-in-mathematics) and [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6659).